# Hashing salting being performed multiple times

Tags: hash, passwords, salt

In a tutorial about hashing and salting password I saw the hash+salt being performed multiple times by using a for loop.

```
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
    { 
        $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
    }
```

What is the advantage of using such a method? Is it more secure against for example brute force methods?
Also: Should I be considering another hashing algorithm other than sha256? I know there is no clear-cut answer because it's likely to depend on many factors such as degree of safety, speed etc. But are there any recommendations for let's say a fairly simple website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to iterate the hashing many times, is to slow down the calculation. Today (in 2013) you can calculate about [1.4 Giga SHA256 hashes](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) per second with common hardware, so you can brute-force a whole english dictionary with about 500'000 words in a fraction of a millisecond.

That's why one should use a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt or PBKDF2 to hash passwords. Using some milliseconds for a login is no problem, but brute-forcing with only 1000 words per second is not practicable.

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and password_verify() ready, to simplify generating BCrypt hashes. I strongly recommend to use this excellent api, or it's [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. The usage is very straightforward:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

If you are interested in a more detailed answer, you may have a look at my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about safely storing passwords.

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough answer. Your tutorial is a great recommendation for beginners like myself in the area of hashing and salting passwords.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

is one of the more well used soltuions, I would look at implementing that.

The reason loops like that exist are to slow down the hashing process. Revese lookup tables take longer because there are more calculations in place.

by having that loop there you have slowed someone scanning for passwords by up to 65536 times.